# Обработка множественных запросов на RxJava

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, rxjava

Есть поле для вводе текста, допустим ищем пользователей по имени в БД.
Есть метод (упрощенный), который выполняется при каждом наборе символа.

```
    public void loadUsers(){
        getUsers(mName)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(users -> {
             //отображение данных
            }, throwable -> {
             //обработка ошибки
            });
}
```

Проблема данного метода в том, что при быстром наборе текста вполне вероятна ситуация, когда ответ на предпоследний запрос пришел позже, чем на последний. Тогда отображаемые данные будут не соответствовать введенному тексту.
Вопрос: как обработать запросы в том порядке, в котором выполнялись?
Или, может быть, можно игнорировать предыдущие запросы? 
P.S. С использованием RxJava.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант можно хранить `Subscription` и её сначала обнулять, а потом новый запрос слать. Типа как-то так (за названия методов не ручаюсь):

```
Subscription s;

    public void loadUsers() {
        if(s != null && !s.isUnsubscribed()){ 
            s.unsubscribe(); 
        }
        s = getUsers(mName)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(users -> {
                 //отображение данных
                }, throwable -> {
                 //обработка ошибки
                });
    }
```

Comment: `s.unsubscribe();`

Comment: @mit, исправил, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы легко обработать эту ситуацию можете использовать библиотеку [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding). Она переводит слушатели на `Rx` что даёт нам легко воспользоваться оператором `debounce()`. Почитать про оператор можно [здесь](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html).

Должно получиться примерно так:

```
public void loadUsers(){
    RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(mNameEditText)
        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map(TextViewAfterTextChangeEvent::editable)
        .map(Editable::toString)
        .flatMap(name -> getUsers(name))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(users -> {
            //отображение данных
        }, throwable -> {
           //обработка ошибки
        });
}
```